# Multiple SPA with JWT Authentication with Refresh Tokens

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, single-page-application, jwt, refresh-token

I have a weird scenario. I want to have a single backend API with multiple SPAs as frontend (all under the same domain but different subdomains). Here was the original idea for using JWT and Refresh tokens.

1. User logs in using USN/PWD.
2. Server Authenticates the request and sends back a JWT with an expiration and permission in claims.
3. The server sets a refresh token (that is stored in a data store for sessions) in a cookie for the domain and all subdomains.
4. Now all request send the JWT and cookie to the server.
5. If the JWT is expired then check that the refresh cookie is still valid and send a new JWT

Now if the user is in a different SPA under the same domain we can send a request to `/token?grant_type=refresh_token` which will send a JWT token if refresh token is stored in a cookie.

I would like to know drawbacks to this approach.

Another approach I read (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29088725/4664675) looks interesting as the JTI is basically the sessions ID.

I am not too worried about 15 minutes expiration tokens and a refresh token of about 1-week sliding session. All connection from the SPA to API are over HTTPS as well.

What would someone recommend the best way to handle this situation (One login that is used for many apps like Google does for mail, drive, photos, youtube, etc.)? I like the idea of JWT so that I don't have to hit the datastore on every request.

A little further down the road, I would like to make native apps that consume the same API so an authentication and authorization process that can handle both would be ideal! Seems like I need a Single Sign On approach?

PS. This is all from research and this will be the first authentication/authorization workflow that I will be writing.